# Как сделать отправку смс без отправки формы

Tags: javascript, php, html, api

Есть форма для отправки данных, к ней пытаюсь прикрутить подтверждение номера по смс с помощью api. Проблема в том, что при нажатии на кнопку "выслать смс" все данные с формы отправляются. Мне необходимо для отправки смс брать только поле с номером, а отправлять данные с формы только после подтверждения номера.[image: Моя форма]

У меня есть отдельная форма которая отправляет смс на номер и она работает.

```
send_phone.php




<html>
<form method="post" action="/inc/act.php">

<table>

<tr><td>Номер телефона<td><input type="text" name="recipient">
<tr><td><br/>

<tr><td>Код подтверждения<td><input name="code" size="6">&nbsp;
<input type="submit" name="sendsms" value="Выслать код">
<tr><td><br/>


</table>
<tr><td><input type="submit" name="ok" value="Подтвердить">
</form>
</html>
```

Так же есть форма для записи человека на определенное время и она немного не стандартная.
Вот ее не большой кусок.

order_form.php

```
<?php
echo '<div class="b_inp_bl in_comment '.$class_inp_comment.'"><input type="text" name="comment" value="'.$val_comment.'" class="oinp" onblur="if (this.value == \'\')  {this.value = \''.$val_comment1.'\';} outfocus('.$inpn1.')" onfocus="if (this.value == \''.$val_comment1.'\') {this.value = \'\';} infocus('.$inpn1.')" /></div>';


echo '<div class="b_inp_bl in_name '.$class_inp_name.'"><input type="text" name="name" value="'.$val_name.'" class="oinp" onblur="if (this.value == \'\')  {this.value = \''.$val_name1.'\';} outfocus('.$inpn2.')" onfocus="if (this.value == \''.$val_name1.'\') {this.value = \'\';} infocus('.$inpn2.')" /></div>';

if ($conf_form == '0' || $conf_form == '1') {
echo '<div class="b_inp_bl in_mail '.$class_inp_mail.'"><input type="text" name="mail" value="'.$val_mail.'" class="oinp" onblur="if (this.value == \'\')  {this.value = \''.$val_mail1.'\';} outfocus('.$inpn3.')" onfocus="if (this.value == \''.$val_mail1.'\') {this.value = \''.$add_mail.'\';} infocus('.$inpn3.')" /></div>';
}

if ($conf_form == '0' || $conf_form == '2') {
echo '<div class="b_inp_bl in_phone '.$class_inp_phone.'"><input type="text" name="recipient" value="'.$val_phone.'" class="oinp" onblur="if (this.value == \'\')  {this.value = \''.$val_phone1.'\';} outfocus('.$inpn4.')" onfocus="if (this.value == \''.$val_phone1.'\') {this.value = \''.$add_phone.'\';} infocus('.$inpn4.')" /></div>';
?>
```

Проблема в том что я не могу сообразить как правильно их соединить.

Comment: Что-то мне подсказывает, что у вас кнопка "Выслать код" имеет тип "submit". Во-первых, уберите его. Во-вторых, привяжите обработчик клика к кнопке. Внутри обработчика получите содержимое инпута с телефоном и отправляйте на сервер через ajax, где можете делать с ним все что захотите. А вообще, в таких случаях лучше прикладывать код формы, а не ее скрин. Впрочем, так лучше делать здесь всегда.

Comment: сейчас немного подробней постараюсь описать проблему

Comment: Нужно воспользоваться нехнологией ajax, flex - XMLHttpRequest

Comment: нерепутал flex с Fetch :)